# Custom Function Keras, Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tf.keras

I want to estimate F in this equation using a Dense neural network. Y = F(X) @ U.
F is a 3x3 matrix, U, X and Y are 3x1 vectors.
I create following network,

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np



def define_model(lr=0.01):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=3))
    model.add(Dense(9 ) )

    # compile model
    opt = SGD(learning_rate=lr, momentum=0.0)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

But I don't know how to train this network.
Please help me.

Comment: Please expand on what you need (e.g. equations/psedo code)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.